# git-bash.exe in context menu with custom command

Tags: git, command-line, windows-10, contextmenu, windows-10-desktop

I would like to get a context menu entry like `Git Bash here`, with an additional command processed.

The command I want to call is `git clean -xdf --dry-run`

What I have done so far is to add an extra entry in the regedit with the suffix `-c <command>`, but it is not working. The windows pops up and closes immediately.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe when the script exits so does the terminal? Have you tried adding `-i` to make the terminal interactive?

Comment: It close anyway. Doesn't matter if I add `-i`

Comment: Consider using a `.bashrc` file? https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/63s7mv/noob_automatically_run_a_set_of_commands_when/

Comment: I don't want to invoke this command everytime I open the git-bash, only if required. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command works, but it does not use the `git bash`. it uses the internal command prompt:

`cmd.exe /C "git clean -xdf --dry-run -i"`